# Queries in a loop does not work in node-firebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebird

I perform several select queries in a loop.

Simplifying the example for reproduce, I got the following code:

```
var Firebird = require('node-firebird');

Firebird.attach({database: 'TEST'}, (err, db) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    db.query('select count(0) from rdb$database', (err, result) => {
      console.log(result);
      //db.detach();
    })
  }
  db.detach();
})
```

This code don't output anything.

But if I reduce the iteration of the loop to two, I’ll get the result:

```sh
[{COUNT: 1}]
[{COUNT: 1}]
```

Why select works twice, but stops working for a third time and more?

Actually I need to execute in a loop selects, inserts and others.

Comment: `db.detach` is called *before* the query statements have stopped executing, because those are called asynchronously. Why this works with two iterations, I don't know, I would expect it to never work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.detach` is called *before* the query statements have stopped executing, because those are called asynchronously. Why this works with two iterations, I don't know, I would expect it to never work.

You can use async/await, combined with promises to call asynchronous code in order, like this:

```
var Firebird = require('node-firebird');

Firebird.attach({database: 'TEST'}, async (err, db) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        db.query('select count(0) from rdb$database', (err, result) => {
            console.log(result);
            resolve();
        });
    });
  }
  db.detach();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But this does not explain why, after commenting db.detch() everywhere, select still does not work...
As I understand it, I should use db.query() only with async/await or in nested callbacks.